# I'm trying to write to a file and getting an error message in Windows Forms

Tags: windows-forms-designer

```
if (File.Exists(path))      //Check if file exist or not
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);//create an instance of StreamWriter
                sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                sw.WriteLine(richTextBox2.Text);
                sw.Close();               
            }
```

I do this and I get an error message like this:
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Wednesday, September 17, 2014Essay.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Although it doesn't look like I have any other windows trying to access that folder, before this I can create the file but I cannot write to it! What's going on?

All the best,
E

Comment: Are you reading the file anywhere else in your code?

Comment: It says "used by another process" but that's only accurate for debugged code.  You have another bug in your code, probably somewhere near where you read the file.  Pretty important to learn how to use the *using* statement, it takes just one exception to get this problem.  One that bypasses the Close() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use StreamWriter in using block to avoid keeping the file locked by mistake anywhere else in your code

```
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path) )
{
      sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
          sw.WriteLine(richTextBox2.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your StreamWriter can't write to that file because it is being used by another process. Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine what process is locking that file. (Once you run Process Explorer, hit Ctrl-F to search for a handle or dll substring and try looking for part of that filename, e.g., "2014Essay".)